# Creeping line in Linux

Tags: linux, text, ads

I have computer with Linux (Gentoo), which play movies (via mplayer) and display HTML pages (via Firefox) in the hall of our building ( some kind of information and advertisement display ) . Now I need to add such feature as creeping lines. They should be displayed on top of mplayer and Firefox and I need to have possibility to change text, background, size and font of text. Before I will start to develop such application from the beginning, may be somebody know such already existing tool?

Comment: You may also want to ask this on superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

You could search for OSD (on screen displays) for linux and try to abuse these. ) A quick search returns [osd-lyrics](http://lifehacker.com/5607580/osd+lyrics-turns-your-linux-media-player-into-a-karaoke-machine) and [xosd](http://ldots.org/xosd-guide/xosd_guide-onepage.html). The latter looks much like what you look for.

Comment: +1. I think `xosd` was used once to display ads in Ukrainian subway. Creating this thing from scratch doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean the crawling text we see at the bottom of some TV news broadcasts.

This was asked about in a previous SO question in relation to the iphone. I found it by Googling "crawling text display" but I've lost the link now.

Maybe you can find it and adapt it.